# PHP: preg_replace returns nothing if given string includes parenthesis

Tags: php

I am writing a php script that guesses a tag based on given input. When returning guessed tags I want to highlight the part of the tag that the user searched for.

```
$search = "fict";
$tag = "fiction";
$suggested = preg_replace('/'.$search.'/', '<span style="background: yellow;">$0</span>', $tag, 1);
echo $suggested;
```

returns `<span style="background: yellow;">fict</span>ion`

```
$search = "someg";
$tag = "someguy_(artist)";
$suggested = preg_replace('/'.$search.'/', '<span style="background: yellow;">$0</span>', $tag, 1);
echo $suggested;
```

However whenever I use a tag that includes parenthesis nothing is returned. How do I make sure my script works with all string inputs?

Edit: I had used capturing groups in a previous test, however I forgot to change the placeholder to $0. Nevertheless my code still does not work with parenthesis in the string.

Edit 2: I just changed my error level and got the following error for the part of my code that includes parenthesis. `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 9 in C:\wamp64\www\project\includes\tags.php on line 18`

Comment: Both your codes are not working with `$1` but work with `$0` - https://3v4l.org/hvqI1

Comment: You __definitely__ show us wrong example. I presume `(` is in `$search` variable. Only in this case you can get such warning.

Comment: You should use [`preg_quote($search)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) when you build the search `regex`, otherwise it doesn't work if `$search` contains [characters that have special meaning in `regex`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this instead?

```
$search = "someg";
$tag = "someguy_(artist)";
$suggested = preg_replace('/'.$search.'/', '<span style="background: yellow;">'.$search.'</span>', $tag, 1);
echo $suggested;
```

I don't see the need for the placeholder in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Both of your code examples don't have any capturing groups (ie symbols in `()`), that's why `$1` is **not** available. Only `$0` is available, so your code can be rewritten as:

```
$suggested = preg_replace('/'.$search.'/', '<span style="background: yellow;">$0</span>', $tag, 1);
echo $suggested;
```

Sample fiddle is [here](https://3v4l.org/hvqI1).

**Update**: according to the text of your warning, you have parenthesis is **`$search`** variable, not in `$tag`. To avoid this warning, escape parenthesis with `preg_quote`:

```
$suggested = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($search).'/', '<span style="background: yellow;">$0</span>', $tag, 1);
echo $suggested;
```

Another fiddle is [here](https://3v4l.org/idqC9).